# How can my webpage interact with an iframe PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf, iframe, itext

I'm not sure what I want to do can be done.

Big picture. I'm loading a form fillable PDF and presenting it to the user who can interact with it. Currently the user then has to save the altered PDF and re-upload it to replace the existing fillable values.

What I want is to accomplish the replacement with a single button click. I would prefer to intercept the PDF's save click and use that to grab the altered PDF and update the values in the database.

It would be slightly less optimal to have a button on the webpage that grabs the altered PDF without it being saved to the local drive.

Here's how I render the PDF.

```
      <div id="Current_Character" name="Current_Character" style="width: 100%; height: 1000px">
        <iframe id="Current_Character_Frame" name="Current_Character_Frame" style="width: 100%; height: 1000px"></iframe>
    </div>
```

And a little jquery call to load it:

```
    function charPDF(id) {
        var url = "/CharPDF?s=" + $('#session').val() + "&ch=" + $('#charid').val() + "&w=10&h=10&m=1";
        $("#Current_Character_Frame").attr('src', url);
    }
```

EDIT: The plan now is to pro grammatically add a submit button at top or bottom of a pdf. The first thing is to simply add a button that does nothing. I am using itextsharp. I expected to see a button labeled "TEST" on the pdf, but there is none.

```
            PdfReader rdr = new PdfReader(filepath);
            PdfStamper stm = new PdfStamper(rdr, new FileStream(outpath, FileMode.Create));
            stm.FormFlattening = false;
            if (AddSubmit)
            {
                var buttonPosition = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(36, 36, 559, 800);

                PushbuttonField buttonField = new PushbuttonField(stm.Writer, buttonPosition, "TEST");

                stm.AddAnnotation(buttonField.Field, 1);

            }
```

Comment: Please share your code using jsbin or jsfiddle

Comment: you can't do that the way you want, but you could use a regular form and then generate the pdf with those fields already filled out. also, that's not ajax.

Comment: No. I can't. I'm constrained to filling in a pdf with values stored in a db and presenting the pdf. I cannot use a regular form.

Comment: There is no more code to share. Why would I want to clutter things with jsfiddle? What value does jsfiddle add to the proposition?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a submit button to the PDF that will send the entire file, saved data and all, to the server where you can then use a PDF Library tool to extract the data from the filled fields. The sumbission isn't a an attachment in a multipart form, it's the body. You just save the body to a file and you've got the PDF.

This assumes Adobe Reader is the PDF viewer.

[image]

Comment: Okay. I'm trying to add a button to the pdf using itextsharp. I would expect the pdf to have a button at the top with the word "TEST" in it. But there isn't one there.

Comment: Why are you using iText Sharp to add the button? Are the forms being created dynamically?